# How to pluck name from related model in select box

Tags: laravel

I am trying to show the name of the company but it is a related Model

```
A company has Stocks
A Stock belongs to a Company
```

I have tried this:

```
$userStocks = \Auth::user()->stocks->pluck('type', 'id')->toArray();

{!! Form::select('name', $userStocks, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Pick Your Stock']) !!}
```

But I don't know how can I get the name of the company which owns that stock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the data and create an array for the `Form::select()` manually by using the `map()` helper. Something like:

```
$stocks = Stock::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
               ->with('company')
               ->get()
               ->map(function($i) {
                   return [$i->id => $i->type.' - '.$i->company->name];
               });
```